# How to figure out from Microsoft Access Connection String for linked table where the data is coming from?

Tags: ms-access, odbc, connection-string, 32bit-64bit, dsn

I have an old (created circa 1997 I believe) Microsoft Access database that has a linked table, to which only Windows XP users can connect.

When I do the following in the Immediate window

```
?CurrentDb.TableDefs("my linked table name").Connect
```

I see the following connection string:

> ODBC;DSN=(some data source name);UID=(uid);PWD=(pwd);APP=2007
>   Microsoft Office
>   system;DATABASE=(someDbName);Network=(someNetworkName);

I can't figure out based on this connection string where it's trying to connect to.  For example, I would expect a machine name instead of a Network name. I tried loading up the ODBC data source administrator on the machine where the connection does work, but I can't see any data source name matching the one above. I'm also not sure what the 'APP' attribute means... is that supposed to be the app from which we're connecting, or the app to which we're connecting?

I suspect that I just need to install a driver, but I have no idea which one to install.

Can anyone suggest a way I can figure out where this linked table is linked to?

Comment: there's TWO odbc managers in windoze. \windows\system32\odbcad.exe for 64bit DSNS, and \windows\syswow64\odbcad.exe for 32bit dsns. Given it's an old app, it's probably 32bit,a nd you were looking at the 64bit manager. Why is it backwards like this? Only the idiots at microsoft who blindly cling to the "backwards compatibility uber alles" mentality know.

Comment: Can't agree more with the last part. This issue is incredibly annoying and stupid

Comment: @pabrams if the application can connect to the table, then your issue is almost certainly what Marc explains because the connection string clearly shows `DSN=` which leads to an entry in the ODBC control panel; There you will find the driver, RDBMS and target database. You can't make a direct connection with that kind of string as no driver is even specified

Comment: Thanks guys, unfortunately I can't try this until I'm back onsite, but I'll post back here when I do.

Comment: *"I tried loading up the ODBC data source administrator on the machine where the connection does work, but I can't see any data source name matching the one above"* - Did you check all three (3) tabs: "User DSN", "System DSN", and "File DSN"? Was that machine in fact running Windows XP? (If so, then it is probably 32-bit. Otherwise, you'd want to check both the 32-bit and 64-bit ODBC Data Sources.) Also, were you logged in as an actual user for whom the application works (in case the DSN is not a System DSN)?

Comment: Well, Access cannot use ODBC to connect to a access database. So clearly this is connecting to a non access database. The server and database do seem to exist in your connection string - that thus should suggest the location of the linked table - but it not a Access table.

Comment: Thanks Gord and Albert, when I do get back onsite, I think I will check the registry, under both HKLM/software/ODBC and HKLU/software/ODBC, which seems to be a reasonable way to find odbc data sources on a machine. Gord, I did check all three tabs but I suspect it was a 64-bit machine and that I was looking at the wrong ODBC administrator. @Albert, thanks for the information "Access cannot use ODBC to connect to a access database", I was not aware of that.

Comment: The answer to my question was basically to find the DSN, which I tried, but didn't realize there was a different ODBC manager for 32bit. I ended up exporting the DSN's from the registry of a working 32-bit machine, and editing them to go to WOW6432Node of HKLM/Software and imported them to 64-bit machines and installed appropriate driver (specified in DSN) and everything worked. Marc B's and Thomas G's comments, and Gord and Albert had some useful stuff to say too, led to solving my problem. So if one of you guys wants to add an appropriate answer I'll accept it.

Comment: As a future suggest, if you create a file DSN as opposed to a machine DSN, then Access becomes DSN-less. You are then free to copy the application to different machines without having to copy a DSN file or even setup the DSN in the registry (for a machine DSN). So I would re-link the tables, choose file dsn, and re-link after creating a new file dsn. If you LOOK CLOSE at the new connection string you see no “DSN”. At that point you can freely copy the database to any machine and not have any setup required for the connection nor is ANY dsn required to be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to find the DSN referenced by the connection string, because it had the server name to connect to (as well as a pointer to a driver). I ended up exporting the DSNs from the registry of a working 32-bit machine, and editing them to go to WOW6432Node of HKLM/Software and imported them to 64-bit machines and installed appropriate driver (specified in DSN) and everything worked.